# how to control the volume of ipad without MPvolumeView?

Tags: iphone, ipad, iphone-sdk-3.2

In a movie player, i can use mpVolumeView to control the volume.Is there any other way to control it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MPMusicPlayerController setVolume:]

Comment: [NSSound setVolume:]must be a API of MAC OS X,i just working at Iphone OS.At the same time [AVAudioPlayer setVolume:] is working with AudioPlayer,but here it's a moviePlayer.Anyway,thank you all the same.